# NSDateFormatter format for a specific string

Tags: ios, ios7, nsdateformatter

If 'string' looks something like this '2014-03-04T15:06:54.000Z', what should this line look like? myDate is getting set as nil with the below format.

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"];

+ (NSDate *)convertStringtoDate:(NSString *)string {

    NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"];

    NSDate *myDate = [formatter dateFromString:string];

    return myDate;
}
```

Furthermore, I'd appreciate a good resource for learning how to look this up on my own. The date formatting concept is a tough one for my tiny cerebral.

Comment: You need to deal with the fractional seconds. And don't quote the timezone

Comment: @rmaddy I'd love an example...

Comment: The string comes from a Rails/Postgres DB, why would I want fractional seconds anyway? I don't need that level of accuracy. Maybe that's my issue?

Comment: But the string you posted has fractional seconds therefore your date format must handle it.

Comment: @rmaddy example? Also, I have control over the datasource if I need to change it.

Comment: Read the docs for the format specifiers to see what to use or find one of the many existing questions that covers this already. If you don't want the fractional seconds then don't include them when you generate the date string. Either way, the date formatter must match the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using "SSS" as format specifier to catch milliseconds, even if you don't use them. Your format string would then become:

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"];
```

See here for formatting reference: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns.

Comment: You're welcome ;) And please don't forget to mark the question as answered if it solved your problem!

Comment: Do not quote the `Z` in the date format. That's the timezone. You want it processed, not ignored.

Comment: @rmaddy like this "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"? Thanks.

Comment: @rmaddy is right, but I'm not sure you should be using SSSZ. I *think* you should be using SSSX (according to the link provided in my answer).